# Solve for eigenvector (complex eigenvalue)

Tags: linear-algebra

The complex eigenvalue is confusing me. $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2}(5 \pm i\sqrt{3})$

for $$A=\begin{pmatrix}3&1\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}$$

so I get this for $\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2}(5 - i\sqrt{3})$ (I multiplied both equations by $2$):

\begin{equation}
(1+i\sqrt{3})x+2y=0 \\
-2x - (1+i\sqrt{3})y = 0
\end{equation}

How do I solve for the eigenvector now? Thanks.

**Edit**

I don't think I fully understand the process of calculating eigenvectors
\begin{equation}
(1-i\sqrt{3})[(1+i\sqrt{3})x+2y=0]\\
-2x - (1+i\sqrt{3})y = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
4x+(2-2i\sqrt{3})y=0\\
-2x - (1+i\sqrt{3})y = 0
\end{equation}

This gives me $x=0$ and $y=0$. Does that mean there is no eigenvector?

Comment: There is really no difference when solving for complex eigenvectors. You substitute your eigenvalue into $A-\lambda I$ and you row reduce as usual for the nullspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try multiplying the first equation by $1-i\sqrt{3}$. It should make things easier for you.

Keep in mind that complex eigenvalues don't really change your procedure for finding eigenvectors at all. Of course, if you've never encountered them before, they can be a bit alarming.

Comment: I did what you suggested and I get x=0, y=0. Please check my edited question. Thanks.

Comment: Ah! I see the problem. Your second equation should be $$-2x-(1-i\sqrt{3})y=0,$$ not $$-2x-(1+i\sqrt{3})y=0.$$ That should fix things for you.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly.